# Why is benchmarking a specific task in multiple languages considered too broad?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I posted a question about what is the fastest way to combine [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files with headers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211461/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-combine-100-csv-files-with-headers-into-one). It has a very specific instruction how I calculate the benchmark and I have got very insightful comments and answers.

The reason for the close of the question was that "it's too simplistic and likely as much to do with I/O subsystem performance as much as any specific tool's relative merits".

I want to disagree with both of these statements:

First, my benchmarking seems to be showing that it is very tool specific and not I/O bound because the times range in orders of magnitude.

Second, according to my previous experiments reading files and manipulating them at the same time is a pretty complicated matter. In my previous experiment I was playing with C and C++ to read and manipulate the data and always got times longer than Python.

I understand that I ask about multiple programming languages and tools and therefore my question is in this sense broad. But I still feel that my problem is pretty specific and there are lots of people who concatenate csv files on a daily basis.

So could someone explain why benchmarking a specific task in multiple languages is considered too broad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question starts with:

> What is the fastest way to combine 100 CSV files with headers into
>   one?

Actually, this makes it a too broad question candidate. RAM limitations, CPU limitations?

Your question goes like that:

> A general assumption is that all files can easily fit in memory

Which had to be combined to the question.

After that you give examples from sed, awk, R, Spark, Python Pandas. Let's think about Spark. It may work on different computers and they can change the performance of the result.

So, define the limitations: RAM, CPU, will run on single node, file size, etc.

On the other hand, this is not an algorithm question and there may be infinite libraries which can work faster than other. However, if such a question is well defined, it can be moved to reopened (even there are infinite libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is really frustrating not to understand what people really mean by too broad.